# Authentication ACS - Allow only few live ids to login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, azure, wif, acs

I am trying to authenticate users on one of my website using ACS. I am using Windows Live as identity provider. I want to restrict access to few Live Ids only. How should I do that. Do I need to have a custom Identity provider for this?

Comment: In bare wif I would have my custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager and refuse all other Name claims except these few. Definitely not a custom identity provider as you want live to be your provider, don't you?

Comment: @WiktorZychla , Yes I want live to be the identity provider. Ok so I would have to do it at application level. Wouldn't that be good, if I could have done that at ACS level.

Comment: Would Azure AD be an option instead of ACS?

Comment: @Gaurav that can be. But I am not sure whether I can use Windows Live as identity provider in AD.

Comment: Sure you can. See if this approach makes sense: Create a brand new Azure AD. One of the ways you can add users into that AD is by providing the Live IDs. So what you do is add the users you want to grant access to your application by their live ids and have your application authenticate against that AD. AD will delegate the actual authentication process to Microsoft Account.

Comment: @Gaurav, I will surely try it. I wasn't aware of all the possibilities with AD. Thanks

Comment: Awesome. Do share your findings.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that with **ACS**! When used as IdP with ACS, LiveID (Microsoft Account) does not deliver Name nor e-mail claims. Thus you cannot differentiate who has logged in, only that some has logged in.

There is an option to do that with Azure AD self. As Guarav describes (don't know why he didn't post it as answer though). So, you can have an Azure AD tenant. In this tenant you can add your Live ID as external accounts. And now you can configure your application to only trust that Azure AD.

Another option is to go entirely manual way with [LiveID SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404787.aspx). By using either [Web Authentication SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676633.aspx) or [Delegated Authentication SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287637.aspx) you can build your authentication. These SDK will pass you the user's e-mail address (LiveID) if you request it and if the user grants it to you. Then you can decide locally in your application whether this user can access it or not.